# How to replace the buffer without slowing down the undo system?

Tags: buffers, text-editing

Say I have a command that operates on the entire buffer.

The simple solution is to:

- Run the command taking the entire buffer as input.
- Store the output.
- Clear the current buffer.
- Insert the new contents.

The problem with this is it's quite slow and it seems the undo system stores a lot of data for this operation.

In cases where only a few changes are made - is there a way to only apply changes - in a way doesn't require the heavy operation of replacing the entire contents?

Something like creating a diff and applying it, instead of replacing the entire buffer, however it need not use the diff format.

Or do I need to write my own code to detect differences and apply them as edits?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: AFAIU, the goal is to transform the contents of buffer A to match the contents of buffer B without changing the text which is identical in both buffers.  Hence "Something like creating a diff and applying it, instead of replacing the entire buffer".

Comment: I would expect a solution based on `diff` and `diff-apply-hunk` to be a sensible approach here.  I don't know that it would be a *lighter* approach as such, but I think it would *tend* to achieve the aim of not using so much undo data.

Comment: I just learned something I didn't know.  When calling `(diff OLD NEW &optional SWITCHES NO-ASYNC)`, `OLD` and `NEW` can each be buffers (despite the docstring indicating they must be files).  I discovered this courtesy of the `diff-buffer-with-file` implementation, which passes a buffer object.  The `diff` function uses `diff-file-local-copy` to create a local temp file as necessary.

Comment: (Documentation bug report raised.  Hopefully fixed for 27.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs-26 introduced `replace-buffer-contents` specifically to do that job.

But use it with care: it works well when there are few differences, but if the new content happens to be completely different from the old it can be a lot more costly.

Comment: Works perfectly!