# Adding a new code formatter

Tags: doom, erlang-mode

How can I add a custom formatter that will be picked up by doom-emacs' `format` (`(format +onsave)`) module?

I want to run the `erlfmt` program on save when editing Erlang files, but I'm not sure how I should configure that.

Doom seems to be using https://github.com/lassik/emacs-format-all-the-code under the hood, so I tried adding the following to `config.el`:

```
(define-format-all-formatter erlfm
  (:executable "erlfm")
  (:install (macos "brew install erlfmt"))
  (:languages "Erlang"
  (:format (format-all--buffer-easy executable "-")))
```

However, this just gives me the error “Don't know how to format erlang-mode code” when I run `format-all-buffer`. (I get the same error if I change to `:languages "erlang-mode"`.)

Comment: This seems very close to: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54351/2418 - not sure it's an exact duplicate though.

Comment: Did you reload your `config.el` (or restart emacs ) after the change?

Comment: Please copy the important part of the linked pages to the question, since these pages may change or even disappear.

Comment: @Stefan Good point. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, putting the following in `config.el` worked:

```
(set-formatter! 'erlfmt  "erlfmt -" :modes '(erlang-mode))
```